# How to modify the shading of an arc in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been trying for the last few days to make a gauge with a needle where a segment of the background colour of the ring changes.

I would like to update the colours of an arc in a gauge I have created in d3.js

I have created this gauge with this arc:

```js
var randomConfigObject = {
    size      : 200,
    clipWidth     : 200,
    clipHeight     : 110,
    ringInset     : 20,
    ringWidth     : 20,

    pointerWidth    : 10,
    pointerTailLength   : 5,
    pointerHeadLengthPercent : 0.9,

    minValue     : 0,
    maxValue     : 10,

    minAngle     : -90 - 45,
    maxAngle     : 90 + 45,

    transitionMs    : 750,

    majorTicks     : 5,
    labelFormat     : d3.format(',g'),
    labelInset     : 10,

    arcColorFn     : d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#e8e2ca'), d3.rgb('#3e6c0a'))
};

var planeStringImage = "M 439.48098,95.969555 L 393.34268,142.46481 L 305.91233,133.41187 L 324.72376,114.58551 L 308.61525,98.464215 L 276.15845,130.94677 L 185.25346,123.08136 L 201.15145,107.27643 L 186.46085,92.574165 L 158.32,120.73735 L 45.386032,112.12042 L 15.000017,131.66667 L 221.20641,192.48691 L 298.26133,237.01135 L 191.91028,345.62828 L 152.82697,408.6082 L 41.549634,393.05411 L 21.037984,413.58203 L 109.25334,470.93369 L 166.38515,558.95725 L 186.8968,538.42933 L 171.35503,427.06371 L 234.28504,387.94939 L 342.81586,281.51396 L 387.305,358.63003 L 448.07703,565.00001 L 467.60778,534.58989 L 458.99769,421.56633 L 487.16033,393.38134 L 473.14247,379.35235 L 456.6139,395.97492 L 448.79636,303.63439 L 481.25315,271.15184 L 465.14464,255.03055 L 446.33321,273.8569 L 436.04766,185.1164 L 482.35108,138.7864 C 501.1942,119.92833 560.62425,61.834815 564.99998,14.999985 C 515.28999,23.707295 476.1521,61.495405 439.48098,95.969555 z ";
var planeStyleElement = "opacity:1;color:#000000;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;marker:none;visibility:visible;display:inline;overflow:visible";

var tickDataLabel = ['S', '210', '240', 'W', '300', '330', 'N', '030', '060', 'E', '120', '150', 'S'];

var gauge = function(container, configuration, config) {
    var that = {};
    var range = undefined;
    var r = undefined;
    var pointerHeadLength = undefined;
    var value = 0;

    var minAngle = 0;
    var maxAngle = 0;

    var counter = 0;

    var svg = undefined;
    var arc = undefined;
    // a linear scale that maps domain values to a percent from 0..1
    var scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0,1])
        .domain([config.minValue, config.maxValue]);
    var ticks = undefined;
    var tickData = undefined;
    var pointer = undefined;
    var minpointer = undefined;
    var maxpointer = undefined;
    var plane = undefined;

    var donut = d3.layout.pie();

    function deg2rad(deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    function newAngle(d) {
        var ratio = scale(d);
        var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
        return newAngle;
    }

    function configure(configuration) {
        var prop = undefined;
        for ( prop in configuration ) {
            config[prop] = configuration[prop];
        }

        console.log('what is the configuation?');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(config));

        range = config.maxAngle - config.minAngle;
        r = config.size / 2;
        pointerHeadLength = Math.round(r * config.pointerHeadLengthPercent);



        // ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
        ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
        tickData = d3.range(config.majorTicks).map(function() {return 1/config.majorTicks;});
        console.log('what is the tick data?');
        console.log(tickData);

        // tickData scale


        arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(r - config.ringWidth - config.ringInset)
            .outerRadius(r - config.ringInset)
            .startAngle(function(d, i) {
                var ratio = d * i;
                return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
            })
            .endAngle(function(d, i) {
                var ratio = d * (i+1);
                return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
            });
    }

    function createNewArc() {
        return arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(50)
            .outerRadius(70)
            .startAngle(deg2rad(20))
            .endAngle(deg2rad(45))
    }

    that.configure = configure;

    function centerTranslation() {
        return 'translate('+r +','+ r +')';
    }

    function isRendered() {
        return (svg !== undefined);
    }
    that.isRendered = isRendered;

    function render(newValue) {
        svg = d3.select(container)
            .append('svg:svg')
            .attr('id', 'gauge')
            .attr('width', config.clipWidth)
            .attr('height', config.clipHeight);

        var centerTx = centerTranslation();

        var arcs = svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'arc')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);

        arcs.selectAll('path')
            .data(tickData)
            .enter().append('path')
            .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                return config.arcColorFn(d * i);
            })
            .attr('d', arc);

        var lg = svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'label')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);
        lg.selectAll('text')
            .data(ticks)
            .enter().append('text')
            .attr('transform', function(d) {
                var ratio = scale(d);
                var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
                return 'rotate(' +newAngle +') translate(0,' +(config.labelInset - r) +')';
            })
            .text(config.labelFormat);


        var planeData = [ [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0],
            [4, -pointerHeadLength],
            [-(config.pointerWidth * 4), 0],
            [0, config.pointerTailLength],
            [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0] ];

        var svgPlaneData = [ [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0],
            [4, -pointerHeadLength],
            [-(config.pointerWidth * 4), 0],
            [0, config.pointerTailLength],
            [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0] ];


        var lineData = [ [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0],
            [0, -pointerHeadLength],
            [-(config.pointerWidth / 2), 0],
            [0, config.pointerTailLength],
            [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0] ];


        var pointerLine = d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone');

        // var pgplane = svg.append('g').data([planeData])
        //     .attr('class', 'planestyle')
        //     .attr('transform', centerTx);

        var pgplane = svg.append('g').data([planeData])
            .attr('id', 'svgplane')
            .attr('transform', ' rotate(-45 100 100)');

        var pg = svg.append('g').data([lineData])
            .attr('class', 'pointer')
            .attr('id', 'pointer')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);

        var pgmin = svg.append('g').data([lineData])
            .attr('class', 'minpointer')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);

        var pgmax = svg.append('g').data([lineData])
            .attr('class', 'maxpointer')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);

        // Shoot in plane direction in a directive
        plane = pgplane.append('path')
            .attr('d', planeStringImage/*function(d) { return pointerLine(d) +'Z';}*/ )
            .attr('style', planeStyleElement)
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +config.minAngle +')');

        pointer = pg.append('path')
            .attr('d', pointerLine/*function(d) { return pointerLine(d) +'Z';}*/ )
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +config.minAngle +')');

        minpointer = pgmin.append('path')
            .attr('d', pointerLine/*function(d) { return pointerLine(d) +'Z';}*/ )
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +config.minAngle +')');

        maxpointer = pgmax.append('path')
            .attr('d', pointerLine/*function(d) { return pointerLine(d) +'Z';}*/ )
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +config.minAngle +')');

        update(newValue === undefined ? 0 : newValue);
    }
    that.render = render;

    function update(newValue, newConfiguration) {
        // d3.select("body").append("svg")
        //     .attr("width", width)
        //     .attr("height", height)
        //     .append("g")
        //     .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

        createNewArc();
        console.log('what is the counter?');
        console.log(counter);
        counter++;

        if ( newConfiguration  !== undefined) {
            configure(newConfiguration);
        }
        var ratio = scale(newValue);
        var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
        pointer.transition()
            .duration(config.transitionMs)
            .ease('elastic')
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +newAngle +')');

        if(minAngle >= newAngle) {
            minAngle = newAngle;
        }

        if(maxAngle <= newAngle) {
            maxAngle = newAngle;
        }

        if(counter === 5) {
            maxAngle = newAngle + 5;
            minAngle = newAngle - 5;
            // Account for baseline doing something different on first iteration
            counter = 1;
        }

        minpointer.transition()
            .duration(config.transitionMs)
            .ease('elastic')
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +minAngle +')');

        maxpointer.transition()
            .duration(config.transitionMs)
            .ease('elastic')
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +maxAngle +')');
    }
    that.update = update;

    configure(configuration);

    return that;
};

function onDocumentReady() {
    var config = {
        size      : 200,
        clipWidth     : 200,
        clipHeight     : 110,
        ringInset     : 20,
        ringWidth     : 20,

        pointerWidth    : 10,
        pointerTailLength   : 5,
        pointerHeadLengthPercent : 0.9,

        minValue     : 0,
        maxValue     : 10,

        // adding angles to make cirle - could be a semicircle gauge

        minAngle     : -90 - 45 - 45,
        maxAngle     : 90 + 45 + 45,

        transitionMs    : 750,

        majorTicks     : 1,
        labelFormat     : d3.format(',g'),
        labelInset     : 10,

        arcColorFn     : d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#e8e2ca'), d3.rgb('#3e6c0a'))
    }

    var powerGauge = gauge('#power-gauge', {
        size: 300,
        clipWidth: 300,
        clipHeight: 300,
        ringWidth: 60,
        maxValue: 10,
        transitionMs: 4000
    }, config);
    powerGauge.render();

    function updateReadings() {
        // just pump in random data here...
        // document.getElementById('power-gauge').remove();
        console.log('what is powergage?');
        console.log(powerGauge);
        console.log();
        randomConfigObject.minAngle = randomConfigObject.minAngle + 20;

        var randomValue = Math.random() * 10;
        config.minAngle = randomValue * 10;

        var powerGauge2 = gauge('#power-gauge', {
            size: 300,
            clipWidth: 300,
            clipHeight: 300,
            ringWidth: 60,
            maxValue: 10,
            transitionMs: 4000
        }, config);

        // powerGauge.render();
        // powerGauge.update(randomValue + 1);
        powerGauge.update(randomValue);
    }

    // every few seconds update reading values
    updateReadings();
    setInterval(function() {
        updateReadings();
    }, 5 * 1000);
}

if ( !window.isLoaded ) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        onDocumentReady();

        // Very dodge way of doing this!
        document.getElementById('pointer').append(document.getElementById('plane'));
    }, false);
} else {
    onDocumentReady();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family:  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 32px;
 }

 #power-gauge g.arc {
  fill: steelblue;
 }

 #power-gauge g.pointer {
  fill: #3ed850;
  stroke: #32ad40;
 }

 #power-gauge g.minpointer {
  fill: #4593f9;
  stroke: steelblue;
 }

 #power-gauge g.maxpointer {
  fill: #e85116;
  stroke: #b64011;
 }
 
 #power-gauge g.label text {
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  fill: #666;
 }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js"></script>
<div id="power-gauge"></div>
<br>
<svg width="1200" height="600" viewBox="0 0 900 350">
 <g id="plane" style="" transform="translate(-55) scale(0.15, 0.15) rotate(-45 100 100)">
  <defs id="defs0"></defs>
  <path id="planepath" d="M 439.48098,95.969555 L 393.34268,142.46481 L 305.91233,133.41187 L 324.72376,114.58551 L 308.61525,98.464215 L 276.15845,130.94677 L 185.25346,123.08136 L 201.15145,107.27643 L 186.46085,92.574165 L 158.32,120.73735 L 45.386032,112.12042 L 15.000017,131.66667 L 221.20641,192.48691 L 298.26133,237.01135 L 191.91028,345.62828 L 152.82697,408.6082 L 41.549634,393.05411 L 21.037984,413.58203 L 109.25334,470.93369 L 166.38515,558.95725 L 186.8968,538.42933 L 171.35503,427.06371 L 234.28504,387.94939 L 342.81586,281.51396 L 387.305,358.63003 L 448.07703,565.00001 L 467.60778,534.58989 L 458.99769,421.56633 L 487.16033,393.38134 L 473.14247,379.35235 L 456.6139,395.97492 L 448.79636,303.63439 L 481.25315,271.15184 L 465.14464,255.03055 L 446.33321,273.8569 L 436.04766,185.1164 L 482.35108,138.7864 C 501.1942,119.92833 560.62425,61.834815 564.99998,14.999985 C 515.28999,23.707295 476.1521,61.495405 439.48098,95.969555 z " style="opacity:1;color:#000000;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;marker:none;visibility:visible;display:inline;overflow:visible" id="path1"></path>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Is there a way I change the colour of the arc over time? So every second, it moves and behaves like this but with a needle that moves too:

https://c3js.org/samples/chart_gauge.html

Thanks.

Comment: Your example is nearly there. All that's missing is that you paint an _additional_, partial arc on top of your beige background one. Compare this to the example you linked: There is a `<g class="c3-chart-arcs-background">` there for the background, plus a partial `<g class="c3-chart-arc c3-target c3-target-data">` arc that's painted on top of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the advice from @Florian I have managed to layer a second arc on top which moves when updated with data.

I have attached it to this post incase anyone else is interested.

```js
var randomConfigObject = {
    size: 200,
    clipWidth: 200,
    clipHeight: 110,
    ringInset: 20,
    ringWidth: 20,

    pointerWidth: 10,
    pointerTailLength: 5,
    pointerHeadLengthPercent: 0.9,

    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: 10,

    minAngle: -90 - 45,
    maxAngle: 90 + 45,

    transitionMs: 750,

    majorTicks: 5,
    labelFormat: d3.format(',g'),
    labelInset: 10,

    arcColorFn: d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#e8e2ca'), d3.rgb('#3e6c0a'))
};

var startAngleGlobal = 0;
var endAngleGlobal = 0;

function subarcCreator(newArc, innerRadius, outerRadius, start, end) {
    var tau = 2 * Math.PI; // http://tauday.com/tau-manif

    console.log('what is new arc?');
    console.log(newArc);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(innerRadius)
        .outerRadius(outerRadius);

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height"),
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var foreground = g.append("path")
        .datum({startAngle: start, endAngle: 0.127 * tau})
        .style("fill", "orange")
        .attr("d", arc);

    startAngleGlobal = start;
    endAngleGlobal = 0.127 * tau;

        function arcTween(newAngle) {
        newAngle = tau * newAngle;
        return function(d) {
            var interpolateStart = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle, newAngle - 0.25);
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
            return function(t) {
                console.log('what is the d?');
                console.log(d);
                d.startAngle = interpolateStart(t);
                d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
                return arc(d);
            };
        };
    }

    return {
        arc: foreground,
        arcTween: arcTween
    };
}

var planeStringImage = "M 439.48098,95.969555 L 393.34268,142.46481 L 305.91233,133.41187 L 324.72376,114.58551 L 308.61525,98.464215 L 276.15845,130.94677 L 185.25346,123.08136 L 201.15145,107.27643 L 186.46085,92.574165 L 158.32,120.73735 L 45.386032,112.12042 L 15.000017,131.66667 L 221.20641,192.48691 L 298.26133,237.01135 L 191.91028,345.62828 L 152.82697,408.6082 L 41.549634,393.05411 L 21.037984,413.58203 L 109.25334,470.93369 L 166.38515,558.95725 L 186.8968,538.42933 L 171.35503,427.06371 L 234.28504,387.94939 L 342.81586,281.51396 L 387.305,358.63003 L 448.07703,565.00001 L 467.60778,534.58989 L 458.99769,421.56633 L 487.16033,393.38134 L 473.14247,379.35235 L 456.6139,395.97492 L 448.79636,303.63439 L 481.25315,271.15184 L 465.14464,255.03055 L 446.33321,273.8569 L 436.04766,185.1164 L 482.35108,138.7864 C 501.1942,119.92833 560.62425,61.834815 564.99998,14.999985 C 515.28999,23.707295 476.1521,61.495405 439.48098,95.969555 z ";
var planeStyleElement = "opacity:1;color:#000000;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;marker:none;visibility:visible;display:inline;overflow:visible";

var tickDataLabel = ['S', '210', '240', 'W', '300', '330', 'N', '030', '060', 'E', '120', '150', 'S'];

var gauge = function(container, configuration, config) {
    var that = {};
    var range = undefined;
    var r = undefined;
    var pointerHeadLength = undefined;
    var value = 0;

    var minAngle = 0;
    var maxAngle = 0;

    var counter = 0;

    var svg = undefined;
    var arc = undefined;
    // a linear scale that maps domain values to a percent from 0..1
    var scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, 1])
        .domain([config.minValue, config.maxValue]);
    var ticks = undefined;
    var tickData = undefined;
    var pointer = undefined;
    var plane = undefined;

    var donut = d3.layout.pie();

    function deg2rad(deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    function testDraw(arcs, lowestGustAngle, highestGustAngle) {
        console.log('inside test function');

        range = config.maxAngle - config.minAngle;
        r = config.size / 2;
        pointerHeadLength = Math.round(r * config.pointerHeadLengthPercent);

        // ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
        ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
        tickData = d3.range(config.majorTicks).map(function() {
            return 1 / config.majorTicks;
        });

        var innerRadius = r - config.ringWidth - config.ringInset;
        var outerRadius = r - config.ringInset;

        var newArc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(r - config.ringWidth - config.ringInset)
            .outerRadius(r - config.ringInset)
            .startAngle(deg2rad(lowestGustAngle))
            .endAngle(deg2rad(highestGustAngle));

        var pi = Math.PI, width = 600, height = 400;
        var iR = 170;
        var oR = 110;
        var cur_color = 'limegreen';
        var new_color, hold;

        console.log('what is the inputs?');
        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('newarc'));

        // var foregroundArc = subarcCreator(newArc, innerRadius, outerRadius, deg2rad(lowestGustAngle), deg2rad(highestGustAngle));
        //
        // foregroundArc.arc.transition()
        //     .duration(750)
        //     .attrTween("d", foregroundArc.arcTween(deg2rad(highestGustAngle)));

        // stop duplication
        if (document.getElementsByClassName('newarc').length > 0) {
            arcs.selectAll('g')
                //animation
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
                .transition()
                .duration(4000);
        }

        var svg1 = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr('class', 'newarc')
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
            .transition()
            .duration(4000);

        arcs.selectAll('d')
            .data(tickData)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .append('path')
            .attr('fill', 'green')
            .transition()
            .duration(4000)
            .attr('d', newArc);

        ////////////////////

    }

    function configure(configuration) {
        var prop = undefined;
        for (prop in configuration) {
            config[prop] = configuration[prop];
        }

        range = config.maxAngle - config.minAngle;
        r = config.size / 2;
        pointerHeadLength = Math.round(r * config.pointerHeadLengthPercent);


        // ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
        ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
        tickData = d3.range(config.majorTicks).map(function() {
            return 1 / config.majorTicks;
        });

        // tickData scale
        arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(r - config.ringWidth - config.ringInset)
            .outerRadius(r - config.ringInset)
            .startAngle(function(d, i) {
                var ratio = d * i;
                return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
            })
            .endAngle(function(d, i) {
                var ratio = d * (i + 1);
                return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
            });

        var pi = Math.PI, width = 600, height = 400;
        var iR = 170;
        var oR = 110;
        var cur_color = 'limegreen';
        var new_color, hold;

        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

        var background = svg.append("path")
            .datum({endAngle: 90 * (pi / 180)})
            .style("fill", "#ddd")
            .attr("d", arc);// Append background arc to svg


        var foreground = svg.append("path")
            .datum({endAngle: -90 * (pi / 180)})
            .style("fill", cur_color).attr("d", arc); // Append foreground arc to svg


        var max = svg
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (iR + ((oR - iR) / 2)) + ",15)") // Display Max value
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-family", "Helvetica").text(max); // Set between inner and outer Radius
// Display Min value
        var min = svg
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + -(iR + ((oR - iR) / 2)) + ",15)") // Set between inner and outer Radius
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-family", "Helvetica").text(min);

// Display Current value
        var current = svg
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + -(iR / 4) + ")") // Push up from center 1/4 of innerRadius
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", "50")
            .style("font-family", "Helvetica")
            .text(current)
    }

    function createNewArc() {
        return arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(50)
            .outerRadius(70)
            .startAngle(deg2rad(20))
            .endAngle(deg2rad(45))
    }

    that.configure = configure;

    function centerTranslation() {
        return 'translate(' + r + ',' + r + ')';
    }

    function isRendered() {
        return (svg !== undefined);
    }

    that.isRendered = isRendered;

    var arcs = undefined;

    function render(newValue) {
        svg = d3.select(container)
            .append('svg:svg')
            .attr('id', 'gauge')
            .attr('width', config.clipWidth)
            .attr('height', config.clipHeight);

        var centerTx = centerTranslation();

        arcs = svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'arc')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);

        // arc gets created at this point
        arcs.selectAll('path')
            .data(tickData)
            .enter().append('path')
            .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                return config.arcColorFn(d * i);
            })
            .attr('d', arc);

        var lg = svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'label')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);
        lg.selectAll('text')
            .data(ticks)
            .enter().append('text')
            .text('hi')
            .attr('transform', function(d) {
                var ratio = scale(d);
                var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
                console.log('index is');
                console.log(ticks);
                return 'rotate(' + newAngle + ') translate(0,' + (config.labelInset - r) + ')';
            })
            .text(function(d) {
                return tickDataLabel[d];
            });
            // .text(tickDataLabel[d]);

        var planeData = [[config.pointerWidth / 2, 0],
            [4, -pointerHeadLength],
            [-(config.pointerWidth * 4), 0],
            [0, config.pointerTailLength],
            [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0]];

        var svgPlaneData = [[config.pointerWidth / 2, 0],
            [4, -pointerHeadLength],
            [-(config.pointerWidth * 4), 0],
            [0, config.pointerTailLength],
            [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0]];


        var lineData = [[config.pointerWidth / 2, 0],
            [0, -pointerHeadLength],
            [-(config.pointerWidth / 2), 0],
            [0, config.pointerTailLength],
            [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0]];


        var pointerLine = d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone');

        var pgplane = svg.append('g').data([planeData])
            .attr('id', 'svgplane')
            .attr('transform', ' rotate(-45 100 100)');

        var pg = svg.append('g').data([lineData])
            .attr('class', 'pointer')
            .attr('id', 'pointer')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);

        var pgmin = svg.append('g').data([lineData])
            .attr('class', 'minpointer')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);

        var pgmax = svg.append('g').data([lineData])
            .attr('class', 'maxpointer')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);

        // Shoot in plane direction in a directive
        plane = pgplane.append('path')
            .attr('d', planeStringImage/*function(d) { return pointerLine(d) +'Z';}*/)
            .attr('style', planeStyleElement)
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' + config.minAngle + ')');

        pointer = pg.append('path')
            .attr('d', pointerLine/*function(d) { return pointerLine(d) +'Z';}*/)
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' + config.minAngle + ')');

        update(newValue === undefined ? 0 : newValue);
    }

    that.render = render;

    function update(newValue, newConfiguration) {
        counter++;

        var randomAngle = Math.random() * 90;

        testDraw(arcs, randomAngle - 50, randomAngle);

        if (newConfiguration !== undefined) {
            configure(newConfiguration);
        }
        var ratio = scale(newValue);
        var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
        pointer.transition()
            .duration(config.transitionMs)
            .ease('elastic')
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' + newAngle + ')');

        if (minAngle >= newAngle) {
            minAngle = newAngle;
        }

        if (maxAngle <= newAngle) {
            maxAngle = newAngle;
        }

        if (counter === 5) {
            maxAngle = newAngle + 5;
            minAngle = newAngle - 5;
            counter = 1;
        }
    }

    that.update = update;

    configure(configuration);

    return that;
};

function onDocumentReady() {
    // var foregroundArc = subarcCreator();
    var config = {
        size: 200,
        clipWidth: 200,
        clipHeight: 110,
        ringInset: 20,
        ringWidth: 20,

        pointerWidth: 10,
        pointerTailLength: 5,
        pointerHeadLengthPercent: 0.9,

        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 12,

        // adding angles to make cirle - could be a semicircle gauge

        minAngle: -90 - 45 - 45,
        maxAngle: 90 + 45 + 45,

        transitionMs: 750,

        majorTicks: 10,
        labelFormat: d3.format(',g'),
        labelInset: 10,

        arcColorFn: d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#ffffff'), d3.rgb('#ffffff'))
    };

    var powerGauge = gauge('#power-gauge', {
        size: 300,
        clipWidth: 300,
        clipHeight: 300,
        ringWidth: 60,
        maxValue: 10,
        transitionMs: 4000
    }, config);
    powerGauge.render();

    function updateReadings() {
        // just pump in random data here...
        // document.getElementById('power-gauge').remove();

        var randomValue = Math.random() * 10;
        config.minAngle = randomValue * 10;

        // powerGauge.render();
        // powerGauge.update(randomValue + 1);
        powerGauge.update(randomValue);
    }

    // every few seconds update reading values
    updateReadings();
    setInterval(function() {
        updateReadings();
        // foregroundArc.arc.transition()
        //     .duration(750)
        //     .attrTween("d", foregroundArc.arcTween(Math.random()));
    }, 5 * 1000);
}

if (!window.isLoaded) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        onDocumentReady();

        // Very dodge way of doing this!
        document.getElementById('pointer').append(document.getElementById('plane'));
    }, false);
} else {
    onDocumentReady();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family:  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 32px;
 }

 #power-gauge g.arc {
  fill: steelblue;
 }

 #power-gauge g.pointer {
  fill: #3ed850;
  stroke: #32ad40;
 }

 #power-gauge g.minpointer {
  fill: #4593f9;
  stroke: steelblue;
 }

 #power-gauge g.maxpointer {
  fill: #e85116;
  stroke: #b64011;
 }
 
 #power-gauge g.label text {
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  fill: #666;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="power-gauge"></div>
<br>
<svg width="1200" height="600" viewBox="0 0 900 350">
 <g id="plane" style="" transform="translate(-55) scale(0.15, 0.15) rotate(-45 100 100)">
  <defs id="defs0"></defs>
  <path id="planepath" d="M 439.48098,95.969555 L 393.34268,142.46481 L 305.91233,133.41187 L 324.72376,114.58551 L 308.61525,98.464215 L 276.15845,130.94677 L 185.25346,123.08136 L 201.15145,107.27643 L 186.46085,92.574165 L 158.32,120.73735 L 45.386032,112.12042 L 15.000017,131.66667 L 221.20641,192.48691 L 298.26133,237.01135 L 191.91028,345.62828 L 152.82697,408.6082 L 41.549634,393.05411 L 21.037984,413.58203 L 109.25334,470.93369 L 166.38515,558.95725 L 186.8968,538.42933 L 171.35503,427.06371 L 234.28504,387.94939 L 342.81586,281.51396 L 387.305,358.63003 L 448.07703,565.00001 L 467.60778,534.58989 L 458.99769,421.56633 L 487.16033,393.38134 L 473.14247,379.35235 L 456.6139,395.97492 L 448.79636,303.63439 L 481.25315,271.15184 L 465.14464,255.03055 L 446.33321,273.8569 L 436.04766,185.1164 L 482.35108,138.7864 C 501.1942,119.92833 560.62425,61.834815 564.99998,14.999985 C 515.28999,23.707295 476.1521,61.495405 439.48098,95.969555 z " style="opacity:1;color:#000000;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;marker:none;visibility:visible;display:inline;overflow:visible" id="path1"></path>
 </g>
</svg>

<br>
```